# asset.first().getUrl('transform') not working for s3 asset - Craft CMS 2.6.2980

Tags: assets, image-transforms, s3

I can load the s3 image fine using the s3 base path and the craft cms filename that is saved in the craft cms database:

`<img src="{{cdnUrl}}/filepath/{{entry.Image.first().filename }}" />`
renders
`<img src="cdn.imageurl.com/filepath/filename.jpg" />`

However if I want to access the same image without the s3 base path (e.g. in order to use an image transform), I get a null.

`<img src="{{entry.Image.first().getUrl('transform')}}" />`
renders
`<img src="" />`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does it work if you call `getUrl()` without the transform argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need to have the URL prefix set under the Asset Settings in order to call .getUrl()
[image]

Once I added this, my transforms began working.

Comment: Be sure to configure the protocol correctly as well. https:// http:// or //